# How to add change certificates issued by letsencrypt?

Tags: lets-encrypt

As far as I understand the [letsencrypt FAQ](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/frequently-asked-questions-faq/26), the recommended way to use the certificates on multiple subdomains is to use the Subject Alternative Name (SAN).

I my case I have a growing number of subdomains where I can not predict the names. This means that I have to **change** the certificate everytime a subdomain comes along to the existing subdomains.

How can I **change** an existing certificate? Simply renewing with an additional SAN seems not to work.

For what it's worth, this is how I'm renewing the certificate:

```
    letsencrypt certonly --standalone \
    --email ssl@example.org \
    --renew-by-default \
    --agree-tos \
    -d www.example.org \
    -d example.org \
    -d client-a.example.org \
    -d client-b.example.org \
    -d client-c.example.org
```

Now I need to add client-d.example.org.

Answer (score 1):

If you add new SANs without the `--expand` flag, a new certificate directory will be created, something like `/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com-0001`. If you want to extend the current certificate, just append the `--expand` flag.

However, if you can't predict the subdomains, Let's Encrypt is currently not the right thing for you. It's the one use case that really needs wildcard certificates. And Let's Encrypt doesn't currently offer wildcard certificates.

Comment: And if you want to *remove* a DNS name from an existing certificate, currently you have to re-issue the certificate ([bug](https://github.com/certbot/certbot/issues/2071)).